# How to see javascript syntax errors in xcode?

Tags: javascript, xcode, weinre

I am building a hybrid app on xcode.

There is headache to find out javascript errors in xcode.

You know in eclipse we can see all javascript syntax error as well as logs on eclipse console.
Here in xcode i cant able to see any javascript syntax errors in xcode console.

Yeah, using [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) tool u can able to see javascript logs but again there is no way to see javascript syntax errors.

Help me, is there any ways?

Thanks!